# Youtube API, make sure a video was watched till end?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I would like to use the YouTube API to make sure the video was watched till end, maybe an event or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`onStateChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events) event, which will give you `0` when ended. This event fires whenever the player's state changes. The value that the API passess to your event listener function will specify an integer that corresponds to the new player state.

Here's a sample code snippet to get notified when the player's state changes:

```
player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
if(state === 0){
// the video is end, do something here.
}
});
```

Here's another way to get notified when state changes:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

Comment: Thank  you, I'll check it out!

Comment: No worries mate! :)